# Why does the schedule function hang, and never print the csv?

Tags: python, web-scraping, schedule, tweets

This schedule function hangs/freezes, and never prints out the expected `csv` file.

Here is the code:

```
import schedule
import time
import tweepy
import csv

def job ():
    

    from textblob import TextBlob



    consumer_key= '-'
    consumer_secret = '-'

    access_token = '-'

    access_token_secret = '-'


    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)



    public_tweets = api.search('gold')

    with open('tweets.csv','r') as tweet:
        data = list(csv.reader(tweet))


    writer = csv.writer(open("/Users/j/tweets.csv",'w'))
    for tweet in public_tweets:
        analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
        writer.writerow([analysis.sentiment])
        print(analysis.sentiment)


    schedule.every(0.1).minutes.do(job)
    #schedule.every().hour.do(job)
    #schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do (job)
 
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

i run it but the function does not write the .csv

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `schedule.every(0.1).minutes.do(job)` within the `job` function itself. I'm not familiar with this framework, but I suspect you want to do that outside of the job function (as it currently stands, job would have to be invoked to schedule job).